# Using Visual Studio, how do I compare two git commits while leaving some in between out?

Tags: git, visual-studio, compare, commit

Since we are currently modernizing the code base of a very old Visual Basic style WinForms C# application we add checkins like "Cosmetics" in order to keep those things away from real changes. If we need to compare two commmits (on the same branch) which have one of those "Cosmetics" commit in between we see all the non relevant changes as well of course. Is it possible (maybe with other tools) to mark all the commits to compare and leave the "Cosmetics" ones out? In VS we can only select two commits to compare.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have Git for Windows installed, in the VS installer select 'Git for Windows' in the 'Individual Components' tab.

In Visual Studio right click the file you want to compare, then select 'Git', then 'View History', now in the new History window that opens automatically select one of the commits, and then with Control + Click select the second commit. Now right click on any of the selected commits and select 'Compare commits'.

Hope the above helps you!

it is working for me on
VS 2022 17.8.1
Git for Windows MinGit 2.41.0

Comment: Hi, thank you but I want to compare the whole commit not just a single file.